# Is there a way to change the location of api_token column in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build an application using Auth's Api with the token driver. I have to create a column `api_token` under `users` table to be able to use it. Is there a way to change the location of that column? Let's say I want to store `api_token` in another table. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to move it?

Comment: I want to move the token stuff to another database.

Comment: My question was why do you want to move it?  What benefit is there to having it in a different database?

Comment: The token is not going to be generated by Laravel. The token is created by a server and using Laravel, I want to create the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can move the `api_token` column to a different table.  You'll have to have a foreign key in the other table so you can connect the user with the api token.  Whenever you want to reference it in regards to a user, you'll have to have a [join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#joins) inside of your query to retrieve it.

Here's an example of how you could structure your tables:

```
Users Table:
id | Name | Email
```

---

```
Other Table:
id | user_id | api_token | created_at
```